# diff file creation with list

Tags: r, list

I have a DataFrame of cryptocoin having 10 col. I want to subset data based on the col (coin) and store with the same **coin** filename.csv.

```
  coinData <- split(data,data$coin)
```

It gives a list of 1370 coin when i print it with the list starting with $coinname.

```
  print(coinData)
```

Now, I want to take the individual list and take out its name from the col (coin) and use this to create a seperate csv file with that name.

```
  for(i in 1:length(coinData))
  {  
      coinName=coinData[[i]]$coin  
      write.csv(coinData[[i]],file=paste(coinName,".csv",sep=""))  
  }
```

Mind you that column (coin) is a factor
But It doesnot seem to work.  Why??

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(coinData[1:3])` and of `dput(bitcoinData[1:3])` in the question, please?

Comment: Error in dput[bitcoinData[1:3]] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: The main question doesn't mention `bitcoinData` any more, so just `coinData` will be fine.